# Youtube-dl: Download video with maximum FPS and change FPS using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, video-processing, youtube-dl

I'm trying to download a YouTube video using YouTube-dl and specifying a maximum FPS. I don't want the lowest FPS, but I also don't want an FPS higher than 30. The code below does not work, but it was my best attempt.

```
ydl_opts = {
    'format': '(bestvideo[fps<30]/bestvideo)+bestaudio/best', # CHANGE FOR VIDEO
    'outtmpl': "youtube_video.%(ext)s",
}
print("Downloading YouTube video.")
                
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
     ydl.download([text])
```

If not, can I change the FPS of a video using OpenCV? I tried using `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)` but this doesn't work either.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file)
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
print(fps) # prints 60.0
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
print(fps) # 60.0 again
```

Comment: I don't think it possible using OpenCV. You may use FFmpeg instead. See: [Change framerate in ffmpeg without reencoding](https://superuser.com/questions/1088382/change-framerate-in-ffmpeg-without-reencoding).

Comment: @Rotem Can I download the video with a particular framerate using ydl_opts?

Comment: I didn't understand you correctly, I thought you wanted to modify the framerate after finish downloading the video. I don't know the answer.